# Is it possible to unlock my Samsung Galaxy 3(GT-i5801)?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-apollo, sim-unlocking

I moved to another country and absent-mindedly bought a SIM card for my GT-i5801 (from Orange UK) Now it's asking for a network lock code. I have searched the net and everything points to me going to a "phone" shop to unlock this, however I'm not conversant enough in the local language to understand people yet and want to carry on using my phone.
Is there anyway to unlock this phone? Either that or I have to wait a month until I can get back to the UK.

Answer (score 3):

You should call your carrier in the UK and explain that you need to unlock your phone because you are travelling.  Unless they're being particularly unhelpful a carrier will normally give you the unlock code for that purpose.

**Edit:** It looks like the unlock code may be stored on the device and accessible as with many Galaxy phones, most easily if you are rooted.  Check out [this AndroidForums guide](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-apollo-3/329376-how-network-unlock-your-samsung-i5800-i5801-using-adb.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah nowadays it's very easy to get a phone unlocked and get rid of excessive roaming charges and get the freedom to change network provider. Recently I unlocked my cellphone, not Samsung but Blackberry, in something like 3-4 hours. Lots of vendors can do it like [codes2unlock](http://www.codes2unlock.com) and [myphoneunlock](http://www.myphoneunlock.net), you could try it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to unlock your Samsung Galaxy 3 (GT-i5801) through online mobile unlock services. I would recommend you to use [theunlockarena.com](http://www.theunlockarena.com/samsung-i5801/rs13wp9/) to get the unlock code. You need to specify the IMEI number. Then, they will give you the unlock code through E-mail.

Comment: Thanks but I can't even remember what this phone looks like anymore. :)